# php created files ownership

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, filesystems

I am having a irritating problem concerning the permissions of files created by Wordpress.

When i download plugins using wordpress or uploading images, and even when a php script creates a dir/files it puts the permissions of this folder into a different user/group.

My user does has no access to this file/folder under my own ftp account.

Is there a way to change files/folders ownership created by apache/php/wordpress to my user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu (I don't know if int other distros the files are in the same location) you can edit the file envvars located in /etc/apache2 and restart Apache.

If you can use ACL this is a better solution than changing the user for Apache, more info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the permissions from a php script, you could use the [chown()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) function